# WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action:

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I am getting following exception, please help to solve this issue.

```
Jul 16, 2013 11:18:40 AM org.apache.struts2.components.Form evaluateExtraParamsServletRequest
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: `'HelloWorld1'` in namespace: `''`. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

**`index.jsp`:**

```
<s:form action="HelloWorld1" namespace="/" method="post" >
            <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
            <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >
    <action name="HelloWorld1" class="java.vaannila.HelloWorld">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**`HelloWorld .java`:**

```
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport{
       //execute method
   }
```

Comment: namespace "/" isn't the same as "" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that `Struts 2` couldn't load your XML configuration. Make sure your `struts.xml` is inside `WEB-INF/classes` directory. (The rest of the configuration looks fine.)

Comment: I'm getting same warning while using java annotations. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the configurations are being loaded properly, try removing the namespace attribute or setting `namespace=""` instead of `namespace="/"`.

Answer (score 0):

This warning appears only when you use `devMode`. Turn it off and it should disappear, add the following to the `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>
```