# ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.error:34 - Developer Notification

Tags: struts2

We are trying to migrate from Struts 2.2 to Struts 2.3, after getting to run the project I am seeing the following error in the console,

```
ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.error:34 - Developer Notification
```

I understand that this is because not all parameters are mapped at the action class level, but we receive several parameters in request scope which we dont want to map. How can this error be avoided?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17672894/573032

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the pointer, was wondering any other way to switch this off, since switching the debug mode off might cause a problem or two.

Comment: You could blacklist those params at either the action or interceptor level.

Comment: @CoolTechie The debug mode is slow and how could you control the user who is sending you parameters right to your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `value` from `true` to `false`

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```