# Package[package ognl] of target class[class ognl.MethodFailedException] of target [ognl.MethodFailedException[java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:Factory]]

Tags: java, apache-poi, struts, weblogic12c

I am trying to upload docx file but I can't.

```
if(ext2[1] ! = null && ext2[1].trim().toLowerCase(new Locale("en","US")).equals("docx")){
        fis = new FileInputStream(DotsFormUtil.cleanString(path));
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
    }
```

I am using XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis)

It is showing the following error the moment the code reaches XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);

Package[package ognl] of target class[class ognl.MethodFailedException] of target [ognl.MethodFailedException:Method "saveAttach" failed for object com.dots.action.getDotsMissionAction@34f2ba1a [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:Factory]] or package[package java.lang,Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8] of member [public java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()] are excluded!

I have poi-5.2.5, poi-ooxml-5.2.5, poi-ooxml-full-5.2.5, poi-scratchpad-5.2.5. Kindy advise.

Comment: It should be a warning, not the error. Post a complete stacktrace.

Comment: Package[package ognl] of target class[class ognl.MethodFailedException] of target [ognl.MethodFailedException:Method "saveAttach" failed for object com.dots.action.getDotsMissionAction@34f2ba1a [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:Factory]] or package[package java.lang,Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8] of member [public java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()] are excluded!

This is what it is showing. It is not showing the error. I tried to use try and catch but no error is shown.

Comment: Don't pay attention on it, you can remove it from logs if you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17672894/573032) answer.

Comment: But I am not able to upload my docx file because of XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis); It is also not showing any error on the console. On the frontend it is showing the customise error which is System is unable to proceed with your request.

Comment: No, it is a different problem if you need help for file uploading in Struts2 you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596465/573032) answer.

Comment: Why are you mixing three different versions of Apache POI? I see 5.2.2, 5.2.3 and 5.2.5, which should all be the same version. I'm not sure if it is causing this specific error, but if your mismanaging other dependency versions as well, you might very well have incompatible library versions on the classpath.

Comment: hi  
Mark Rotteveel I am using all the same versions poi-5.2.5, poi-ooxml-5.2.5, poi-ooxml-full-5.2.5, poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.5 and poi-scratchpad-5.2.5 jar

Comment: Your question says something else: _"I have poi-5.2.2, poi-ooxml-5.2.3, poi-ooxml-full-5.2.5, poi-scratchpad-5.2.2."_.